# Java Character.charCount in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have java code written to get string code point at location 0 and then to check the number of characters required to represent that code point . I am looking for equivalent c# method which shall take input as code point and return the character count needed to represent the code point

```
 Below is the **Java** code
 final int cp = str.codePointAt(0);
 int count = Character.charCount(cp);
```

Looking for Equivalent C# code

```
 int cp  =  char.ConvertToUtf32(input, 0);
 int count = ????
```

Comment: The method charCount(int codePoint) just count how many characters are in the specified codepoint(method argument). Basically expects the returned value either 2 or 1. The returned value is 2 if the specified character is equal to or greater than 0x10000, otherwise 1. Expect that most of the time the you would be getting a value of 1 because by right a character length is 1. You can write it yourself.

Comment: Also in C# there is a `Char.IsSurrogatePair(input,i)`, please refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/217eztw8(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs of [`charCount`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#charCount(int)),

> Determines the number of char values needed to represent the specified character (Unicode code point). If the specified character is equal to or greater than 0x10000, then the method returns 2. Otherwise, the method returns 1.

So you can write such a method yourself!

```
public static int CharCount(int codePoint) {
    return codePoint >= 0x10000 ? 2 : 1;
}
```

Or using the new expression bodied members syntax,

```
public static int CharCount(int codePoint) =>
    codePoint >= 0x10000 ? 2 : 1;
```